# What does function (x) in a function parameter list mean in R?

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

The code is the following

```
crossval <- function(data, lambda=0, ytrans=function(x) x)
```

I wanna know what function (x) in a function parameter list mean?if calling the same function again and again or something? If so is it possible to call the function crossval itself?Isthe variable ytrans necessary?cannot we just call the function(x) in the function body?

Answer (score 2):

@duffymo covered it, but here's a bit longer explanation.

What you see there is called an anonymous function. The function basically returns the same objects (= does nothing). This could also be written explicitly as a named function

```
newFunction <- function(x) {
    x
}
```

which would then be

```
crossval <- function(data, lambda=0, ytrans = newFunction)
```

This is the default value, like in `lambda=0`, except the default value is a function itself.

Comment: Technically I think the default value in the OPs case is the return value from the anonymous function, not the function itself if I understand correctly. I don't well understand the use for it though and that would be a helpful explanation to have.

Comment: That's what I meant - it returns (the same) object as it was passed in.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, let's say `newFunction` squares `x` then you could do `foo <- function( x , y ) y(x)` and `foo( 2 , newFunction )` returns `4`. +1

Comment: so its in case we dont supply a value for ytrans,the program executes that function to give it a value?

Answer (score 1):

Default function is one that returns the x value that it's passed.  If you don't supply one, that's the function that will be used.